# How to load Bootstrap tab panel with tab click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap tab panels on the site like that:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#chartcontainer1" aria-controls="chartcontainer1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart 1</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#chartcontainer2" aria-controls="chartcontainer2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart 2</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="chartcontainer1">
      <div id="layeredcolumnchart"></div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="chartcontainer2">
      <div id="piechart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I want to do is to load the non active panels on tab click**.

(Now, it loads every panels on page load.)

*Note: Show-hide is not a solution for me and what I want to show is not an external URL. It's a div (included some JS) from the current page.*

Comment: Make the them hidden and onlick= show

Comment: @Mihai, I don't want to hide-show, I want to load on click because I want to see an animation on load. I can see the animation on default active tab, but I couldn't see the animation on other panels because they loaded before I visit them: on page load.

Comment: can you please create a working snippet or fiddle for this?

Comment: So, loading graphic (a spinner, say) should be displayed when loading a page, otherwise keep loaded data, or *refresh* the data on the tab click?

Comment: Yes, _refresh_ the data on the tab click.

Comment: ...and now the kicker. You mentioned an *on page div* in a few places. Is this a static sheet of data sitting there waiting to be loaded into the tab, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Actually, it's a [chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-pie-chart/) and because this tab is not active at first but loaded at background I couldn't see the "animation". What I want to do is when I click on the tab and then it (the "animation") loads again.

Comment: So, same data (static) but the animation needs to be reloaded on the tab click, is that what I'm hearing?

Comment: @herci, Can you edit the post to use 'runnable' code snippets so others see the problem clearly?

Comment: you need trigger the tab keypress or click on tab nav???

Answer (score 10):

If you wish to load the tab panel content on click of the tab, you have to use Ajax for same.

Here is an example.

HTML Code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
  <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843293/" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
  <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843301/" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
  <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843306/" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">

  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
var $this = $(this),
    loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
    targ = $this.attr('data-target');

$.get(loadurl, function(data) {
    $(targ).html(data);
});

$this.tab('show');
return false;
});
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/rw8ujfg3/) to view the Demo on JSFiddle:-

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work for me because I don't load a external page, I want to load an internal div. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use tab events to (re)load divs inside the tab-content.

For example:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  if (e.target=='#chartcontainer1') {
    $('#layeredcolumnchart').html('YOUR HTML/JAVASCRIPT/ETC HERE');
    // If you need to load jQuery plugins like charts, you need to load 
    // it here each time you display the tab-content
    // $('#layeyedcolumnchart .somediv').somePlugin();
  }
})
```

Look at the Events section on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for a `load animation` with css, not an actual load of information.

Just by adding the classes `fade in` to your active `tabpanel` (your `#chartcontainer1`) and `fade` to the other `tabpanel` you will active this effect.

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="chartcontainer1"><!-- Notice the "fade in" classes -->
      <div id="layeredcolumnchart">...</div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="chartcontainer2"> <!-- Notice the face class -->
      <div id="piechart">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[My JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/p2hppbvo/1/)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for a CSS animation. What I want to do is to load (or re-load) the panel on tab click.

Answer (score 2):

So, after doing a bit of a requirements process, I think I may have a solution.

You need to blow out the content when on a tab, then load the chart app to get the animation.

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#chartcontainer1" aria-controls="chartcontainer1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Chart 1</a></li>

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  if (e.target=='#chartcontainer1') {
     $('#chartcontainer1').html('');
     makeChartOne();
  }
})

function makeChartOne(){
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "#chartcontainer1", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  } ],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
}
```